# How do I make this program smaller, more efficient?

Tags: c++, processing-efficiency

I was doing a practice question that went like this:

Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of Hamburgers eaten
by ten different people (p1, p2, ... etc.)

Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the least hamburgers, and outputs the person who ate the most Hamburgers.

I know my code isn't ideal(to say the least, but I was determined to just finish it so I could have something to go off of for this question. If you're willing to help, don't be afraid to throw some more complex things at me, that's how I learn, right?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

 #include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int p1 = 0;

    int p2 = 0;

    int p3 = 0;

    int p4 = 0;

    int p5 = 0;

    int p6 = 0;

    int p7 = 0;

    int p8 = 0;

    int p9 = 0;

    int p10 = 0;


    cout << "How many pancakes did p1 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p1;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p2 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p2;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p3 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p3;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p4 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p4;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p5 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p5;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p6 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p6;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p7 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p7;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p8 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p8;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p9 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p9;

    cout << "How many pancakes did p10 eat?" << endl;
    cin >> p10;


    // LARGE section of if statements incoming


    // Test to see which person ate the least pancakes

    if (p1 < p2 && p1 < p3 && p1 < p4 && p1 < p5 && p1 < p6 && p1 < p7 && p1 < p8 && p1 < p9 && p1 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p1 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p2 < p1 && p2 < p3 && p2 < p4 && p2 < p5 && p2 < p6 && p2 < p7 && p2 < p8 && p2 < p9 && p2 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p2 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p3 < p1 && p3 < p2 && p3 < p4 && p3 < p5 && p3 < p6 && p3 < p7 && p3 < p8 && p3 < p9 && p3 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p3 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p4 < p1 && p4 < p2 && p4 < p3 && p4 < p5 && p4 < p6 && p4 < p7 && p4 < p8 && p4 < p9 && p4 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p4 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p5 < p1 && p5 < p2 && p5 < p3 && p5 < p4 && p5 < p6 && p5 < p7 && p5 < p8 && p5 < p9 && p5 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p5 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p6 < p1 && p6 < p2 && p6 < p3 && p6 < p4 && p6 < p5 && p6 < p7 && p6 < p8 && p6 < p9 && p6 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p6 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p7 < p1 && p7 < p2 && p7 < p3 && p7 < p4 && p7 < p5 && p7 < p6 && p7 < p7 && p7 < p9 && p7 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p7 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p8 < p1 && p8 < p2 && p8 < p3 && p8 < p4 && p8 < p5 && p8 < p6 && p8 < p7 && p8 < p9 && p8 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p8 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p9 < p1 && p9 < p2 && p9 < p3 && p9 < p4 && p9 < p5 && p9 < p6 && p9 < p7 && p9 < p8 && p9 < p10)
    {
        cout << "p9 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p10 < p1 && p10 < p2 && p10 < p3 && p10 < p4 && p10 < p5 && p10 < p6 && p10 < p7 && p10 < p8 && p10 < p9)
    {
        cout << "p10 ate the least pancakes." << endl;
    }


    // Test to see who ate the most pancakes

    if (p1 > p2 && p1 > p3 && p1 > p4 && p1 > p5 && p1 > p6 && p1 > p7 && p1 > p8 && p1 > p9 && p1 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p1 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p2 > p1 && p2 > p3 && p2 > p4 && p2 > p5 && p2 > p6 && p2 > p7 && p2 > p8 && p2 > p9 && p2 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p2 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p3 > p1 && p3 > p2 && p3 > p4 && p3 > p5 && p3 > p6 && p3 > p7 && p3 > p8 && p3 > p9 && p3 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p3 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p4 > p1 && p4 > p2 && p4 > p3 && p4 > p5 && p4 > p6 && p4 > p7 && p4 > p8 && p4 > p9 && p4 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p4 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p5 > p1 && p5 > p2 && p5 > p3 && p5 > p4 && p5 > p6 && p5 > p7 && p5 > p8 && p5 > p9 && p5 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p5 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p6 > p1 && p6 > p2 && p6 > p3 && p6 > p4 && p6 > p5 && p6 > p7 && p6 > p8 && p6 > p9 && p6 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p6 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p7 > p1 && p7 > p2 && p7 > p3 && p7 > p4 && p7 > p5 && p7 > p6 && p7 > p7 && p7 > p9 && p7 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p7 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p8 > p1 && p8 > p2 && p8 > p3 && p8 > p4 && p8 > p5 && p8 > p6 && p8 > p7 && p8 > p9 && p8 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p8 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p9 > p1 && p9 > p2 && p9 > p3 && p9 > p4 && p9 > p5 && p9 > p6 && p9 > p7 && p9 > p8 && p9 > p10)
    {
        cout << "p9 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }

    if (p10 > p1 && p10 > p2 && p10 > p3 && p10 > p4 && p10 > p5 && p10 > p6 && p10 > p7 && p10 > p8 && p10 > p9)
    {
        cout << "p10 ate the most pancakes." << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To make your program (source) smaller: Remove all the newlines between your `int` declarations ;)

Comment: Use an array for `p1` to `p10`, then use a for loop to find the highest and the lowest elements.

Comment: See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_arrays.htm)

Comment: Use a `for` loop for the input.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review.

Comment: I'll give you props for posting something that appears to work at least and shows logical thinking.

Answer (score 2):

### Vector of Pancake Quantities

Try this:

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned int> Pancake_Container;
const unsigned int MAXIMUM_PARTICIPANTS = 10;
Pancake Container pancake_quantities(MAXIMUM_PARTICIPANTS);
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < MAXIMUM_PARTICIPANTS; ++i)
{
  static const char prompt_text1[] = "\nHow many pancakes did participant #";
  static const char prompt_ending[] = " eat? ";
  cout.write(prompt_text1, sizeof(prompt_text1) - 1U);
  cout << i;
  cout.write(prompt_ending, sizeof(prompt_ending) - 1U));
  unsigned int quantity = 0U;
  cin >> quantity;
  pancake_quantities[i] = quantity;
}

unsigned int max_person_index = 0U;
unsigned int max_pancakes_eaten = 0U;
unsigned int min_person_index = 0U;
unsigned int min_pancakes_eaten = MAX_UINT;
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < MAXIMUM_PARTICIPANTS; ++i)
{
  const unsigned int quantity = pancake_quantities[i];
  if (quantity > max_pancakes_eaten)
  {
    max_person_index = i;
    max_pancakes_eaten = quantity;
  }
  if (quantity < min_pancakes_eaten)
  {
    min_person_index = i;
    min_pancakes_eaten = quantity;
  }
}

cout << "Person #" << max_person_index << " ate " << max_pancakes_eaten << "\n";
cout << "Person #" << min_person_index << " ate " << min_pancakes_eaten << "\n";
```

### Vector of Structures

This one allows sorting to figure out the maximum and minimum.

```
struct Pancake_Info
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int quantity;
    Pancake_Info() : id(0), quantity(0)
        {}
    bool operator < (const Pancake_Info& other)
        {
            return quantity < other.quantity;
        }
};

typedef std::vector<Pancake_Info> Pancake_Container;
Pancake_Container pancake_quantities;
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < MAXIMUM_PARTICIPANTS; ++i)
{
    static const char prompt_text1[]  = "\nHow many pancakes did participant #";
    static const char prompt_ending[] = " eat? ";
    cout.write(prompt_text1, sizeof(prompt_text1) - 1U);
    cout << i;
    cout.write(prompt_ending, sizeof(prompt_ending) - 1U);
    unsigned int quantity = 0U;
    Pancake_Info p_i;
    cin >> p_i.quantity;
    p_i.id = i;
    pancake_quantities.push_back(p_i);
}
std::sort(pancake_quantities.begin(), pancake_quantities.end());
cout << "Minimum of "
     << pancake_quantities[0].quantity
     << " eaten by person "
     << pancake_quantities[0].id
     << "\n";
cout << "Maximum of "
     << pancake_quantities[MAXIMUM_PARTICIPANTS - 1].quantity
     << " eaten by person "
     << pancake_quantities[MAXIMUM_PARTICIPANTS - 1].id
     << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is correct.

revision:
create a struct s1;

with three values - person index, and hamburger count and pancake count.

Fill and put the s1's into a vector

use std::sort on the hamburger count. - print the value(s) you want.

use std::sort on the pancake   count  - print the value(s) you want.

The bigger count will be at one end (and smallest count at the other).

---

revision 5/14/2015:

Time to answer your question - how make smaller.

You simply identify the pattern ... and match it to a for loop.

pattern idea 1 - The personId sequence is 1 to 10;

Leads us to:

```
for (int personId = 1; personId <= 10; ++personId)
{

}
```

For each person, your code prompts for counts - pancakes, then hamburgers:

```
for (int personId = 1; personId <= 10; ++personId)
{
   cout << "How many pancakes did p" << personId << " eat?" << endl;
   int p1 = 0;
   cin >> p1;

   cout << "How many hamburgers did p" << personId << " eat?" << endl;
   int p2 = 0;
   cin >> p2;

   // perhaps these should be joined into a single prompt to get 2 numbers
   // example:
   cout << "Enter pancake count, then hamburger count: " << endl;
   int p1 = 0;
   int p2 = 0;
   cin >> p1 >> p2;
   // error handling is somewhat easier in the 1st style.

}
```

To determine which is the least, or most, I recommend you put these items into a vector to sort.

```
struct S1 {
    int personId;
    int pancakeCount;
    int hamburgerCount;

    // define ctor
    S1(void) : personId(0), pancakeCount(0), hamburgerCount(0)
    {
    }
};

vector<S1> s1Vec;

for (int personId = 1; personId <= 10; ++personId)
{
   cout << "How many pancakes did p" << personId << " eat?" << endl;
   int p1 = 0;
   cin >> p1;

   cout << "How many hamburgers did p" << personId << " eat?" << endl;
   int p2 = 0;
   cin >> p2;

   {
       S1 s1; // declare an instance, and fill in
       s1.personId = personId;
       s1.pancackecount = p1;
       s1.hamburgerCount = p2;

       s1Vec.push_back(s1);  // default cpy-ctor will capture into vec
   } // THIS brace triggers the dtor of s1 ... currently does nothing,
     // but sometimes the intermediate structs / classes need cleaning
}

// now you have all ids and counts captured to the vector

// sort s1Vec by pancakeCount, and 
//  print out s1Vec.begin() and .end()

// sort s1Vec by hamburgerCount, and
//   print out s1.begin() and .end()
```

I suggest you add a show method to S1...

```
struct S1 {
    int personId;
    int pancakeCount;
    int hamburgerCount;

    // define ctor to initialize values
    S1(void) : personId(0), pancakeCount(0), hamburgerCount(0)
    {
    }

    std::string show(void)
    {
       stringstream ss;
       ss << "person: " << personId
           << "    p1: " << pancakeCount
           << "    p2: " << hamburgerCount << endl;
       return (ss.str());
    }

    std::string showP1(void)
    {
       stringstream ss;
       cout << "person: " << personId
            << "    p1: " << pancakeCount << endl;
       return (ss.str());
    }

    std::string showP2(void)
    {
       stringstream ss;
       cout << "person: " << personId
            << "    p2: " << hamburgerCount << endl;
       return (ss.str());
    }

};
```

Good luck.

This reduces size of your code by using a loop and the struct.

Your code can be considered an 'unrolled' loop, which is something you might consider for performance issues.  But hey, **user I/O (prompts and responses) can never be** high performance.

Comment: Your solution looses the correlation between person (index) and the amount of pancakes or hamburgers eaten.  This is why I didn't sort in my answer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - so here I have added the discussion on how to reduce your code size, and why you should not bother with 'performance issues'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the answer has to be so complicated.

It can be done very easy with `vector`:

```
  auto num_eaten = std::vector<int>(10);

  for (auto i = 0u; i < num_eaten.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "Enter number of hamburgers eaten by " << (i + 1) << "> ";
    cin >> num_eaten[i];
  }

  auto min_it = std::min_element(num_eaten.begin(), num_eaten.end());
  cout << (std::distance(num_eaten.begin(), min_it) + 1) << " ate the least"
       << endl;

  auto max_it = std::max_element(num_eaten.begin(), num_eaten.end());
  cout << (std::distance(num_eaten.begin(), max_it) + 1) << " ate the most"
       << endl;
```

or with `map`:

```
  auto eaten = std::unordered_map<int, int>{};

  for (auto i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    cout << "Enter number of hamburgers eaten by " << i << "> ";
    cin >> eaten[i];
  }

  auto min_it = std::min_element(
      eaten.begin(), eaten.end(),
      [](auto const &lhs, auto const &rhs) { return lhs.second < rhs.second; });
  cout << min_it->first << " ate the least: " << min_it->second << endl;

  auto max_it = std::min_element(
      eaten.begin(), eaten.end(),
      [](auto const &lhs, auto const &rhs) { return lhs.second > rhs.second; });

  cout << max_it->first << " ate the most: " << max_it->second << endl;
```